# merge two files, first line from first file followed by first line from second file

Tags: text-processing, merge

I have two files :

```
f1:                                      f2:
==============                         ===============
some text line 1                       A1
some text line 2                       A2
some text line 3                       A3
```

can I quickly merge these two files to produce f3:

```
some text line 1
A1
some text line 2
A2
some text line 3 
A3
```

Comment: `===` is part of the file ?

Comment: No . " === " was just used as separator for showing the file contents

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a job for `paste`:

```
paste -d'\n' f1.txt f2.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat foo.txt 
some text line 1
some text line 2
some text line 3

$ cat bar.txt 
A1
A2
A3

$ paste -d'\n' foo.txt bar.txt 
some text line 1
A1
some text line 2
A2
some text line 3
A3
```

Comment: Wow, I was not aware there is delimiter option for the paste as well. I thought of paste but it combined the contents on the same line. Thank you for your help and quick response. +1

Comment: awesome, I was gonna click on `post your answer` and saw `1 answer` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this using one while loop and read through the two files using `read`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4
do
    printf "%s\n" "$file1" >> mergedFile.txt
    printf "%s\n" "$file2" >> mergedFile.txt
done 3</path/to/file1/file1.txt 4</path/to/file2/file2.txt
```

You can use `echo` instead of `printf`. The results are in mergedFile.txt If the files you are processing are not huge, perhaps the above is easier and more portable than most solutions.

Comment: You can also put the append redirection on the "done" line instead of inside the while block

Comment: +1: `paste` is a better fit for this question, but this is a great example of using extra file descriptors.

Comment: This will stop when `file1` ends. Perhaps `||` would be better?

Comment: What is the '<&3' ?

Answer (score 1):

POSIX Awk; this works with an arbitrary amount of files, and the files don’t
even have to have the same amount of lines. The script keeps going until all
files are out of lines:

```perl
BEGIN {
  do {
    br = ch = 0
    while (++ch < ARGC)
      if (getline < ARGV[ch]) {
        print
        br = 1
      }
  } while (br)
}
```